# What conditions can hold luggage expect during a flight?

Tags: air-travel, luggage

What kind of conditions can my checked luggage expect in the hold of a plane during regional, international and transoceanic flights?

- worst - Most extreme temperature and pressure range during a normal flight without major technical problems
- average - Range of temperatures/pressures typical for a given flight length

Comment: Define worst? Highest? Lowest? fastest change?

Comment: @CMater thanks! Author never sees ambiguatuons ;). I hope now is disambiguated.

Comment: I would worry about handling the baggage and stacking them.. not the temp nor the pressure.

Comment: @HeidelBerGenesis fair point, great you mentioned it, I see it beneficial to other readers/general post audience. Of course that's my biggest worry and I make assumption of them dropping it from 2 meters etc... But that's what I managed to observe during many flight, when it comes to cargo space, I didn't put yet working monitoring device in my baggage to measure...

Comment: The worst? your luggage will end up on the bottom of the ocean - near an underwater volcano.

Comment: Also, if luggage is not containerised on your flight, expect it to be quite wet if it's raining...

Comment: I am pretty sure I've excluded major tragedies in original question, maybe it disappeared during edits of other. Unfortunately I can not check question edit history on phone.

Comment: No, it's still there, "during a normal flight without major technical problems"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pressure is going to be basically the same as the passengers enjoy, as the entire fuselage is pressurized. The only real difference will be temperature, as the cargo hold area is not usually heated to any great degree unless the aircraft is transporting live animals or cold sensitive perishable items.  The cold section of the cargo hold may drop down to 10C (give or take a few degrees), but they wouldn't let it drop below freezing as they don't want bottled liquids in suitcases freezing solid.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I remember that most airlines forced me to deflate the tyres of my bicycle when I want to carry it with me because of the pressure possibly causing an "explosion" of the tyres.

Comment: @Albers The cargo hold is pressurized at the same pressure as the cabin. But the pressure on the whole aircraft is much lower than ground pressure. You would have the same problem if your bicycle was in the cabin.

Comment: The 'rule' about deflating tires is a leftover from the dark ages of air travel.  I constantly travel with my bikes and never let the air out unless I run into a stickler for outdated rules.  Then I put my finger by the valve so it hisses a lot and leads the uninformed to believe I let all the air out. Never had a problem with my fully inflated road bike tires due to hold pressure.

Comment: They want you to let the pressure out in case there is a pressurization problem.  On a normal flight the tires won't pop but if there is a loss of cabin pressure they probably will.  In most airliners the cargo compartments get exactly the same air as the cabin, both temperature and pressure; though not always.

Comment: @nexus_2006  The bike tire deflation rule is a leftover from when aircraft were not fully pressurized and even then was not a really necessary as bike tires can handle any altitude a human can without popping.  In the event of a catastrophic loss of cabin pressure, I am sure bike tires are the least of the airline's concern.

Comment: Actually, tires bursting *is* an airline's concern, because a tire at high pressure contains quite a bit of energy -- a tire explosion can send tire bits all over the place at high speed, which can then damage other things.  (Keep in mind that a fire would be the most likely culprit in an exploding tire, *not* a decompression.)

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject - 1st: most bikes are packed inside cases, boxes, etc for the flight thus containing your fantasized "explosion" - 2nd: bike tires rupture when the pressure gets too high, usually a horizontal tear, they don't exploded into little bits - 3rd: a bike tire involved in a fire would rupture then simply burn. Tires as a general rule do not "explode", with car and truck tires it is not the actual "blow out" that spreads pieces everywhere, rather the fact the vehicle keeps moving and shreds the flattened tire by beating it against the road.

Comment: @Tom -- interesting...well, not sure why then.

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject - it is a perfect example of a policy based on a myth not on facts.

Comment: Typical airline cabin pressure will increase the tire pressure by only about 3 PSI, which is highly unlikely to rupture any tire unless it's already over inflated to start with.